# Where is the criminal?

Tags: geography

A worldwide criminal has been hiding in Japan recently, however nobody knows where he is. The FBI intercepted one of his messages to his team.

> I am hiding in something you won't expect. Maybe you're even wrong. But I have to do this. Just remember:
> Athena Parthenos, Athens, Greece (*used* to be there)
> Palm Jumeirah, Dubai, UAE
> Kansai International Airport, Osaka, Japan
> Golden Gate Bridge, San Francisco, CA, USA
> Brooklyn Bridge, New York, NY, USA
> Statue of Liberty, New York, NY, USA
>
> I am also close to an Eiffel Tower! And good luck!
>
> P.S. I like Emmet's gigantic bot. I'm currently watching *The Lego Movie 2* in my spare time!

Comment: Is he/she/it blind?

Comment: No, why do you ask?

Comment: It could be Vitruvius ;)

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 5):

I think the criminal is at the

> [Unicorn Gundam Statue](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g1066449-d13428361-Reviews-Unicorn_Gundam_Statue-Koto_Tokyo_Tokyo_Prefecture_Kanto.html)

Athena Parthenos, Athens, Greece (used to be there)

> The criminal is hinting at their love of massive statues here.

Palm Jumeirah, Dubai, UAE
Kansai International Airport, Osaka, Japan

> Both of these are artificial island constructions, similar to [Odaiba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odaiba) where the Unicorn Gundam statue is located.

Golden Gate Bridge, San Francisco, CA, USA
Brooklyn Bridge, New York, NY, USA

> Both of these bridges are similar in construction style to the [Rainbow Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_Bridge_(Tokyo)) connecting Shibaura Pier to Odaiba

Statue of Liberty, New York, NY, USA

> Again this shows off the criminal's interest in massive statues.

I am also close to an Eiffel Tower

> [Tokyo Tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Tower)

P.S. I like Emmet's gigantic bot.

> Similar to the Unicorn Gundam

Answer (score 1):

## Partial answer guess

> He is always moving eastward.

> Athens -> Dubai -> Osaka -> San Francisco -> NY -> Paris -> ???

Maybe he is...

> Denmark, where legos where invented.

Comment: FWIW rot13(Gurer'f nyfb na Rvssry Gbjre va Ynf Irtnf, AI. Znlor orpnhfr va gur chmmyr vg ernqf na Rvssry Gbjre vafgrnq bs Gur Rvssry Gbjre - whfg pnyyvat vg bhg)

Comment: @PartyHatPanda rot13(Lrf, V'z njner bs gung, ohg gura ur jvyy abg or nyjnlf tbvat rnfgjneq.)

Comment: rot13(fher, tbbq cbvag, hayrff ur nyfb zrnaf gur fgnghr bs yvoregl naq oebbxyla oevqtr va irtnf nf jryy naq ylvat nobhg gur fgngrf ybpngvba. Pbhyq or pbzcyrgryl bss, ohg gung jbhyq pregnvayl or abg jurer vg jnf rkcrpgrq!)

Comment: I should have made it clearer that he is **in** Tokyo.